# Matplotlib table plotting layout control

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I'm always having problems putting table in the Matplotlib plot. Here is [one example](https://gist.github.com/suntong/79efa35d5a450f651504). I.e., the table and my graph are always overlapping with each other:

[image: table and graph are overlapping]

Now I'm thinking, how about separating them in different subplots? So I tried it, [same example](https://gist.github.com/suntong/79efa35d5a450f651504), second graph. It looks rather bad:

[image: separating them in different subplots]

The problem is I have no idea why my simple changes would make such huge differences. Can somebody help me fixing it please?

Re-posting the scripts:

```
# On Same graph

plt.close('all')  # close all open figures

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# X: pd.options.display.mpl_style = 'default' # cause system freeze
df.set_index(['person']).plot(kind='barh', ax = ax, width=0.85, fontsize=8)
ax.invert_yaxis()

plt.title("Matplotlib table plotting")

#plt.tight_layout()

# Add a table
plt.table(cellText=df.values,colWidths = [0.25]*len(df.columns),
        rowLabels=df.index,
        colLabels=df.columns,
        cellLoc = 'center', rowLoc = 'center',
        loc='top')

# separate them in different subplots

plt.close('all')  # close all open figures

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,1)

# Add a table first
ax[0].table(cellText=df.values,colWidths = [0.25]*len(df.columns),
        rowLabels=df.index,
        colLabels=df.columns,
        cellLoc = 'center', rowLoc = 'center',
        loc='top')

# keep the y tick labels from getting too crowded
#plt.subplots_adjust(hspace = 3.6)

# X: pd.options.display.mpl_style = 'default' # cause system freeze
df.set_index(['person']).plot(kind='barh', ax = ax[1], width=0.85, fontsize=8)
ax[1].invert_yaxis()

plt.title("Matplotlib table plotting")
```

Thanks

Comment: have you tried using `tight_layout`?

Comment: yes, and got the exactly same result.

Comment: Try `subplots_adjust`. It's a little more manual, but it gives finer control.

Comment: No, got the exactly same result regardless whether I'm output inline in iPython or out to a popup figure. Even it is works, I'd rather have a solution than to do manual tweaking each time, because I'll be producing such graphs quite a lot.

Comment: A couple comments: first, it should be possible to find a value for `subplots_adjust`'s `hspace` kwarg that works pretty universally. I make sets of 500 figures with many subplots, with no problem (but some tweaking in the code that produces them in general--but not for specific plots). Second, you could just produce the figures separately and merge them together with ImageMagick.